# Getting fractional second added in queries when application migrated in linux with oracle 12.1 client

Tags: linux, oracle, timestamp, oracleclient

We have migrated application from AIX to Linux Servers. On AIX we were using java 1.6 along with oracle client 11.2 with odbc6. jar application deployed on Websphere application server and in linux we are using java 1.8 along with 12.1 client with odbc6. jar. The issue is that in AIX servers we are not geeting any fraction seconds appending in queries like 2018-10-10 00:00:00 in application logs but in linux we are geeting fraction seconds appended like 2018-10-10 00:00:00.0  resulting application flows are breaking and queries are not executing geeting ORA 01830 error.

Comment: `sysdate` is a date not a timestamp. This sounds like a WebSphere and/or logging config issue rather than anything to do with the database.

Comment: You might have to_date/to_char functions without explicit format strings, relying on some default values. You could try these commands in your launching script: `export NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'; export NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'`

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond so it needs to be added in the. bashrc file in the root user or wasusr on linux server?

Comment: First you should do some experimenting... I hope you have someone with Unix/Linux knowledge.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please, visit [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Provide more info on what you are trying to achieve, efforts you made and code.

Answer (score 0):

The `SYSDATE` function returns a `DATE` data type, which does not have fractional seconds. For that,  you need a `TIMESTAMP` or `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data type. I think those are `LOCALTIMESTAMP` AND `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, but I forget which one is which.